# While I was trying to connect Mondo DB, event.bind stopped working as a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

I've got all the packages necessary and whatnot but I keep on getting an error. First of all, here's my coding (in a file called main.js.):

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
require("dotenv").config();
const fs = require('fs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

["command_handler", "event_handler"].forEach((handler) => {
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord);
});

mongoose
.connect(process.env.MONGODB_SRV, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
})
.then(()=>{
    console.log('Connected to the database!');
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});





client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

My error is

```
C:\Users\shann\Desktop\DiscordBot\handlers\event_handler.js:10
           client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, Discord, client));
                                       ^

TypeError: event.bind is not a function
   at load_dir (C:\Users\shann\Desktop\DiscordBot\handlers\event_handler.js:10:41)
   at C:\Users\shann\Desktop\DiscordBot\handlers\event_handler.js:14:38
   at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
   at module.exports (C:\Users\shann\Desktop\DiscordBot\handlers\event_handler.js:14:25)
   at C:\Users\shann\Desktop\DiscordBot\main.js:11:37
   at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\shann\Desktop\DiscordBot\main.js:10:38)
   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
   at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
   at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

I honestly don't know what the problem is this time. Should I define event.bind? I thought .bind was a function and event was the variable. I've been following a tutorial. I do have mongoose installed through the command center but I don't know if I should reinstall it. Also, I don't see any errors in my coding but I am pretty new so please point them out and how I can fix it!

The coding for command_handler.js

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord)=>{
    const command_files = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for(const file of command_files){
        const command = require(`../commands/${file}`)
        if(command.name){
            client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

The coding for event_handler.js is

```
    const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (client, Discord)=>{
    const load_dir = (dirs)=>{
        const event_files = fs.readdirSync(`./events/${dirs}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for(const file of event_files){
            const event = require(`../events/${dirs}/${file}`);
            const event_name = file.split('.')[0];
            client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, Discord, client));
        }  
    }

    ['client', 'guild'].forEach(e => load_dir(e));
}
```

Comment: Your question title is irrelevant to the actual issue

Comment: I just realized the require function that's causing the problem is for my command handler and event handler. I just associated Mongoose as the problem because my command handler was working fine until I tried to add mongoose. Basically, I don't know if its a problem with Mongoose or my command handler/event handler. (But I'm assuming the problem is with mongoose.) Just some extra info

Comment: Sorry, I just changed the title

Comment: You should check what is exported from the `command_handler.js` and `event_handler.js` files. Could you post them in your question?

Comment: If you mean the coding in them, sure

Comment: Is the `event_handler.js` posted above correct or you missed something? It seems there is nothing exported from there.

Comment: Ok actually, it changed. Let me update the post to show you

Comment: For some reason module.exports didn't show up when I copy and pasted. Also when I tried to rerun things, the error changed

Comment: `['client', 'guild'],forEach` should be `['client', 'guild'].forEach`

Comment: Sorry for asking a lot and thanks for helping me but I have a new error now lol.

Comment: For anyone still wondering, I'm still having this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't actually much of an answer here but the thing is, you don't even need an advanced event handler. All I did was remove the event handler from my handlers and added an event handler to my `main.js`. Then I removed client and guild from my events. After that, I made it so that in `main.js` it would look at all the files in `events` (the folder with all my events) and run them (using fs)!

Credits to @WorthyAlpaca for the help in introducing this alternate method